# Disabling Command Column Buttons in Ext.JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs, ext.net

I have an Ext.NET/Ext.JS MVC project with following grid view in my .cshtml file:

```
@(x.Viewport()
    .ID("MyViewport")
    .Items(x.GridPanel()
        .ID("MyListGrid")
        .View(x.GridView()
            .GetRowClass(a =>
            {
                a.Args = new[] { "record" };
                a.Fn = "MyJs.renderInactiveRow";
            })
            .ID("MyGrid")
            .Store(x.Store()
                .AutoLoad(true)
                .Proxy(x.AjaxProxy()
                    .Url(Url.Action("GetList", "Home"))
                    .Reader(x.JsonReader().RootProperty("data")))
                .Model(x.Model()
                    .Fields(
                        x.ModelField()
                            .Name("Name")
                            .Type(ModelFieldType.String),
                        x.ModelField()
                            .Name("Id")
                            .Type(ModelFieldType.Int),
                        x.ModelField()
                            .Name("IsActive")
                            .Type(ModelFieldType.Boolean))))
            .ColumnModel(
                x.Column()
                    .DataIndex("Name")
                x.CommandColumn()
                    .DisabledCls("non-viewable")
                    .Commands(
                        x.GridCommand()
                            .CommandName("Run")
                            .IconCls("far fa-play-circle")
                            .Cls("btn-action")
                            .Text(Model.RunButtonText))))))
```

My JavaScript file has the following code:

```
renderInactiveRow: function(record) {
    return record.data.IsActive ? null : "inactive non-viewable";
}
```

The `inactive` class corresponds to a .css file that will change the grid row's background color. So far, this portion works. Now I'm trying to make this function also disable the button in the command column and I can't seem to make that happen. I've tried adding a renderer to the column:

```
renderRunBtn: function(value, metadata, record) {
    if (!record.data.IsActive) {
        metadata.tdCls = "non-viewable";
    }

    return value;
}
```

but that hasn't helped either. It seems that `metadata`, the cell reference doesn't actually contain the button but that it is rather attached to the column. So, how do I get this button to disable it? Or is there a better way to do this?